# Problem: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, neural-network

Error message: ValueError. Why does this happen?

Im learning about neural networks from a book i've bought. I've copied the code from that book, but somehow it keeps giving me that error message.

Thank you very much!

.

```
import numpy
import scipy

class neuralNetwork:

    def __init__(self, inputnodes, hiddennodes, outputnodes, learningrate):

        self.inodes = inputnodes
        self.hnodes = hiddennodes
        self.onodes = outputnodes

        self.wih = (numpy.random.rand(self.hnodes, self.inodes) -0,5)
        self.who = (numpy.random.rand(self.onodes, self.hnodes) -0,5)

        self.lr = learningrate

        self.activation_function= lambda x: scipy.special.expit(x)

        pass

    def train():
        pass

    def query(self, inputs_list):

        inputs = numpy.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T

        hidden_inputs = numpy.dot(self.wih, inputs)
        hidden_outputs = self.activation_function(hidden_inputs)

        final_inputs = numpy.dot(self.who, hidden_outputs)
        final_outputs = self.activation_function(final_inputs)

        return final_outputs

        pass


input_nodes = 3
hidden_nodes = 3
output_nodes = 3

learning_rate = 0,3

n = neuralNetwork(input_nodes, hidden_nodes, output_nodes, learning_rate)

n.query([1, 1, 1])
```

I expected an array as output.

```
hidden_inputs = numpy.dot(self.wih, inputs)
```

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: the problem was the commas. thank you. although having edited this, when i run the program, theres no output. how do i create the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ValueError arises due to the fact that you are trying to perform dot product of a tuple with a vector (input vector).

I also noted that you are passing `learning_rate = 0,3`, whereas you are expecting learning rate to be an integer or float in the body of the class. This made me think that probably the **dots(.)** in the book you're reading have been misprinted as **commas(,)**. This could be a probable issue.

Once you fix the three commas with dots, you can see your code run.

Here's the complete code below:

```
import numpy
import scipy
from scipy import special

class neuralNetwork:

    def __init__(self, inputnodes, hiddennodes, outputnodes, learningrate):

        self.inodes = inputnodes
        self.hnodes = hiddennodes
        self.onodes = outputnodes

        self.wih = (numpy.random.rand(self.hnodes, self.inodes)-0.5)
        self.who = (numpy.random.rand(self.onodes, self.hnodes)-0.5)

        self.lr = learningrate

        self.activation_function= lambda x: scipy.special.expit(x)

        pass

    def train():
        pass

    def query(self, inputs_list):

        inputs = numpy.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T

        print(self.wih[0].shape)
        hidden_inputs = numpy.dot(self.wih, inputs)
        hidden_outputs = self.activation_function(hidden_inputs)

        final_inputs = numpy.dot(self.who, hidden_outputs)
        final_outputs = self.activation_function(final_inputs)

        return final_outputs

        pass


input_nodes = 3
hidden_nodes = 3
output_nodes = 3

learning_rate = 0.3

n = neuralNetwork(input_nodes, hidden_nodes, output_nodes, learning_rate)

n.query([1,1,1])
```

*Moreover, please add some context when posting a question to SO. This would help us to understand what you're trying to achieve rather than just fixing the compile-time errors.*

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because of these lines:

```
self.wih = (numpy.random.rand(self.hnodes, self.inodes) -0,5)
self.who = (numpy.random.rand(self.onodes, self.hnodes) -0,5)
```

`(numpy.random.rand(self.hnodes, self.inodes) -0,5)` is a tuple and you are trying to perform the dot product of a tuple with the `inputs` of type `numpy.ndarray`.
So, in order to get rid of error change

`self.wih = (numpy.random.rand(self.hnodes, self.inodes) -0,5)`
to `self.wih = (numpy.random.rand(self.hnodes, self.inodes) -0.5)`

and `self.who = (numpy.random.rand(self.onodes, self.hnodes) -0,5)` to `self.who = (numpy.random.rand(self.onodes, self.hnodes) -0.5)`.

There is also an error with the line where you are initializing `learning_rate` variable, i.e.,

`learning_rate = 0,3`.

It should be `learning_rate = 0.3`. Although, you are not using it in calculation anywhere yet.